# jquery: replace element a with span

Tags: jquery

for information: it's a mobile (off-canvas) menu and it's not visible in page source. it's only visible in mobile view with "code inspector" etc. [the page i'm talking about](http://piirissaareturism.ee/)

my code:

```
 $('.mm-listview li:(:nth-child(2)) .mm-next+a').replace('span');​
```

my html:

```
 <ul class="mm-listview">
 <li><a class="mm-next" href="#mm-2" data-target="#mm-2"></a>
 <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/">Avasta Piirissaar</a>
 </li>
 <li><a class="mm-next" href="#mm-3" data-target="#mm-3"></a>
 <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/">Kasulik info</a>
 </li>
```

it doesn't replace at the moment. i know, it should be something simple...

Comment: I believe you're looking for replaceWith() - http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function)** with callback then generate span with the content and update. Also your selector is invalid so change `li:(:nth-child(2))` to `li:nth-child(2)` for making it valid.

```js
 $('.mm-listview li:nth-child(2) .mm-next+a').replaceWith(function() {
   return '<span>' + $(this).text() + '</span>'
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
my html:

<ul class="mm-listview">
  <li>
    <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-2" data-target="#mm-2"></a>
    <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/">Avasta Piirissaar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-3" data-target="#mm-3"></a>
    <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/">Kasulik info</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Or you can use **[`unwrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap)** and **[`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap)** methods.

```js
$('.mm-listview li:nth-child(2) .mm-next+a').contents().unwrap().wrap('<span/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
my html:

<ul class="mm-listview">
  <li>
    <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-2" data-target="#mm-2"></a>
    <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/">Avasta Piirissaar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-3" data-target="#mm-3"></a>
    <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/">Kasulik info</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you don't want to maintain the element content then use  **[`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)** with the new content.

```js
$('.mm-listview li:nth-child(2) .mm-next+a').replaceWith('<span/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
my html:

<ul class="mm-listview">
  <li>
    <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-2" data-target="#mm-2"></a>
    <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/">Avasta Piirissaar</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-3" data-target="#mm-3"></a>
    <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/">Kasulik info</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

**UPDATE** : There is an additional character after the code just remove it.Check your console you can see the error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

You can see it in the below image at the end as a red mark.

[image]

Comment: added, but now my "hamburger" even doesn't open... :(

Comment: @Gallex : what you mean?

Comment: @Gallex : There is an additional symbol after the code just remove it.

Comment: choosed Pranav C Balan's first solution, cause all others removed element content. thank you!

Comment: @Gallex : glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 $('.mm-listview li:nth-child(2) .mm-next+a').replaceWith('<span></span>');​
```

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you! ;)

Comment: added, but now my "hamburger" even doesn't open... :(

Comment: @Gallex Are you sure your selector is correct then? Looks like you replaced to much.

Comment: sorry. take a look now. span is, but empty

Answer (score -1):

[DEMO LINK](https://fiddle.jshell.net/3u6u9w2v/1/)

**html code**

```
<ul class="mm-listview">
 <li><a class="mm-next" href="#mm-2" data-target="#mm-2">1</a>
 <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/avasta-piirissaar/">Avasta Piirissaar</a>
 </li>
 <li>
 <a class="mm-next" href="#mm-3" data-target="#mm-3">2</a>
 <a href="http://piirissaareturism.ee/kasulik-info/">Kasulik info</a>
 </li>
```

**js code**

```
 $('.mm-listview li:nth-child(2) mm-next+a').replaceWith($('<span />').text('123'));
```

- use replaceWith to replace
- use valid selector [`li:nth-child(2)`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)